# ¿Alguien me puede ayudar con Mysql con un query?

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Disculpa por la molestia estoy desarrollando un sistemas de eventos.

El detalle es que tengo tabla exclusivamente para controlar todos los eventos, lo que estoy intentando realizar es eliminar las filas ya vencidas, cada cierto tiempo con el query de Mysql.

Este es mi Query.

```
CREATE EVENT delete_producto
 ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 hour
DO
  DELETE 
    FROM tickero 
   WHERE duracion < NOW()
```

Este query hace todo bien, pero el problema es cuando cumple su tiempo transcurrido desaparece el código eliminando los datos que ya fueron vencidos.
Lo que yo quiero es que no desaparezca el query y que vuelva a ejecutar automáticamente otra vez tras cada hora así sucesivamente.

¿Hay alguna manera para poner automático y que vuelva  a ejecutar?

Answer (score 0):

intenta reemplazando

```
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 hour
```

por

```
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR
```

Aqui puedes encontrar mas información https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html

Comment: Gracias Marulo, ahora lo voy a intentar haber si me funciona te aviso si.